# ssh, how to enable remote proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I use this `ssh -D 9999 root@my.server.ip`

Then I use firefox and put in the proxy settings as socks 5 , localhost, port 9999

This works fine, but what If I want several other people to use my server as a proxy? They can't connect to my localhost, what can I do? What can I do on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Give each person their own account on the server – with an individual username and password – then tell them to set up a SSH tunnel the same way you do.

Some Linux distributions have `adduser` for this, although the generic tool is `useradd`.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from `man ssh`:

> -D [bind_address:]port

This means you’ll have to specify which address the virtual SOCKS proxy should bind to. If you want it to be available on every interface on your computer, use `*`.

The default behavior is controlled in `ssh_config` (or appropriate more local overrides) with the option `GatewayPorts`:

> Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to local forwarded ports. By default, ssh(1) binds local port forwardings to the loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports. GatewayPorts can be used to specify that ssh should bind local port forwardings to the wildcard address, thus allowing remote hosts to connect to forwarded ports. The argument must be “yes” or “no”. The default is “no”.

Comment: so, `ssh -D * user@my.ip -P 22` ?

Comment: That command line is missing the port. It has to be one of `-D 1234`, `-D 1.2.3.4:1234` or `-D *:1234`.

Comment: It still does not connect. `ssh -D *:9999 user@my.ip -p 22`

Comment: Well, apart from `-p 22` being totally redundant, this command line is correct. So your problem lies elsewhere and as such not within the topic of this question.